# Ignore all output arguments if no variable is assigned

Tags: matlab, function

I have wondered for sometime now if it is possible to write a function in Matlab that does not return an argument if none is requested. For example does `plot` returns the axis handle if it is called as `h = plot(x,y);`, but not if it is called as `plot(x,y);`. It is just that plot is not written in Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short example to demonstrate how to get a flexible number of random outputs:

```
function varargout=myFancyOutput()
    varargout=cell(1,nargout)
    for idx=1:numel(varargout)
        varargout{idx}=rand
    end
end
```

`nargout` gives the number of output arguments and `varargout` is expanded to a list of individual outputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [`varargout`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html), for example:

```
function varargout = test()

    for k = 1:nargout
        varargout{k} = k;
    end

    disp(['Test function called with ', str2num(nargout), ' output arguments']) %// Just so you can see the function working when you call no outputs

end
```

Comment: Ok since you was first I will accept your answer. I actually managed to find it out by myself before :). Thank you anyway

Comment: Actually I think Daniel was a few seconds ahead of me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually when a function returns an output you can just choose not to store it.

Let a function be:

```
function [out1,out2,out3] = testfunction(x,y)
    out1 = 2.*x;
    out2 = 2.*y;
    out3 = x.*y;
    plot(1:10,1:10)
end
```

Now you can call this function using:

```
% Call function interested in no output
testfunction(2,3); % Although in this case `ans` is generated as pointed out by Dan.
% Call function only interested in first output
[out1] = testfunction(2,3)
% Call function only interested in first and second output
[out1,out2] = testfunction(2,3)
% Call function only interested in first, second and third output
[out1,out2,out3] = testfunction(2,3)
% Only the first output
[~,~,out3] = testfunction(2,3)
```

Depending on the assignment of the output the output is generated.

A very dirty work-around to avoid ans being generated is:

```
[~]=testfunction(2,3)
```

This avoids the extra coding telling how much output arguments are needed.

Comment: +1 You should include a test case that is just `testfunction(2,3)` with no output arguments at all. This should still work and just assigns your first output, `out1` to `ans`. However if you want no output at all (i.e. nothing to `ans`), then you'll need to use `varargout`

Comment: Well you will still have a problem with `testFunction(1,2)` returning something. Using the `varargout`-`nargout` property, you can let the call `testFunction(1,2)` be a void function.

Comment: @Dan Or just call [~] = testfunction(2,3), no need for nargout really.

Comment: @EJG89 That's interesting, can't test on Matlab rigth now and the online octave I use doesn't like it. Can you output to multiple variables with `~` first like `[~, out1...`? Because otherwise you'd still need `varargout` to get it to return truly nothing when you ask for nothing, but still give you outputs when you specify them (like the functionality of `plot` described in the question.)

Comment: @patrik I don't know whether calling with [~]=testfunction(1,2) is a true void or that the output is assigned to a temporary variable and is immediately destroyed afterwards, but it works fine anyway (at least on my version of MatLab)

Comment: @Dan Well, in principle the function returns [out1,out2,out3]. So on output is wants to assign to a three element array. It starts counting at the first element, i.e. [a,b,c] = testfunction(1,2) it assigns out1 to a, out2 to b, and out3 to c. If only a and b are asked it only assigns out1 and out2. You can use the tilde to say: ignore out argument, so [~,x,~] = testfunction(1,2) assigns out2 to x. Just by calling the function the plot command is always executed (even in if statements etc.).

Comment: @EJG89 Right the problem is rather the when you do not want an output then you want to do a call `testfunction(1,2)` and nothing are going to be returned. With the `[~]` syntax you especially asks for returning nothing and that is what I tried to get rid of. It is intuitive to only return a value when you request it. This is how it is done in most programming languages, except that most languages generate a compilation error if no return value is assigned. However, then you have void functions instead, which anyway is more complicated than matlabs solution. Anyway thanks for your input.